# In Angular js, how to create a form without submit button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have tried to create an `angular` directive `ng-smart-submit` where there is no submit button. The form is automatically submitted when one of the form elements looses focus.

Here is a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/xP92p3zBwHsXWsOzVefl?p=preview

Here is the directive code:

```
angular.module('plunker').directive("ngSmartSubmit", [
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      require: "ngModel",
      scope: {
       form: "=ngSmartSubmit",
    data: "=ngSmartModel"
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    var action;
    action = function(parentScope) {
      if (ctrl.$dirty) {
        scope.form.$setPristine();
        if (ctrl.$valid) {
          return parentScope.update(scope.data, function(succeed) {
            ctrl.$updated = succeed;
          });
        } else {
          return parentScope.$emit('ngSmartSubmit::controlInvalid');
        }
      }
    };
    ctrl.$updated = false;
    scope.$parent.$on('ngSmartSubmit::controlModified', function() {
      return scope.$apply(function() {
        ctrl.$updated = false;
      });
    });
    return element.bind("focus", function(evt) {
      return scope.$apply(function() {
        ctrl.$updated = false;
      });
    }).bind("blur", function(evt) {
      return scope.$apply(function() {
        return action(scope.$parent);
      });
    }).bind("keydown keypress", function(evt) {
      if (evt.which === ENTER_KEY) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          return action(scope.$parent);
        });
        return event.preventDefault();
      } else {
        return scope.$parent.$emit('ngSmartSubmit::controlModified');
      }
    });
  }
    };
  }
]);
```

Please advice, how could I improve the `ng-smart-submit` directive.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code looks nice!

Comment: A plnkr is not a substitute for adding relevant code into the question. Doing it this way makes the question irrelevant to anyone coming to this later.

Comment: @Liam, I have inserted the code. Please +1

Comment: Much better, thanks. On another note. This question seems a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/